# Get data on firebase database to replace string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I run this function to get data from firebase database

```
app.listen(3000)
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sm = require('sitemap')

var firebase = require('firebase').initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xx",
    authDomain: "xx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xx",
    storageBucket: "xx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xx"
  });

database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('urls');
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function errData(err){
    console.log('Error!');
    console.log(err);
}

function gotData(data){
    var url_sitemap = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(url_sitemap);
    console.log(keys);
}
```

Results is

```
[ 'key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4' ]
```

I need to add data to this 'page-xx/' on below

```
var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({ 
    hostname: 'xxx.com',
    urls: [
        { url: '/page-xx/},
        { url: '/page-xx/},
        { url: '/page-xx/},
        { url: '/page-xx/}
    ]
});
```

How can I replace /page-xx/ with data on database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, using `ES6`:

```
const sitemap = sm.createSitemap({ 
    hostname: 'xxx.com',
    urls: gotData(data)
});

function gotData(data){
    const url_sitemap = data.val();
    const urls = [];
    Object.keys(url_sitemap)
          .forEach(k => urls.push({url: k }));
    return urls;
}
```

In non `ES6`:

```
function gotData(data){
    var url_sitemap = data.val();
    var urls = [];
    var urlKeys = Object.keys(url_sitemap);
    for (var i = 0; i < urlKeys.length; i++) {
      urls.push({url: urlKeys[i] });
    }
    return urls;
}

var urls = gotData(/*-- your data -- */);

var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
    hostname: 'xxx.com',
    urls: urls
});
```

*Note: if you're making an asynchronous call to get this data, you may need to wrap this in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or a `callback`.*

#### UPDATE

```
// store urls:
var urls = [];    

ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function errData(err){
    console.log('Error!');
    console.log(err);
}

function gotData(data){
    var url_sitemap = data.val();
    var urlKeys = Object.keys(url_sitemap);
    for (var i = 0; i < urlKeys.length; i++) {
      urls.push({url: urlKeys[i] });
    }
}

var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
    hostname: 'xxx.com',
    urls: urls
});
```

Comment: `url: gotData(data) -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token` Its errors like this

Comment: still same error as `url: gotData(data) -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

Comment: When you call `gotData` in the `sitemap` call, data needs to be defined.

Comment: @MoomooSoso also, the ES6 syntax might be what is causing the problem here. I will write a non-ES6 solution.

Comment: @MoomooSoso most welcome, I have updated the answer.

Comment: It definitely works for me. Hmmm, try console log within the `gotData` method. Alternatively, assign the result of `gotData` to a variable and had that to `sm.createSitemap({ url: newVariableName })`

Comment: I try console.log(urls) in function is work fine But console.log(urls) outside function got this error `urls is not defined`

Comment: @MoomooSoso I've updated my answer. The reason the `urls` property within the `sm.createSitemap` method is undefined is probably down to when you're invoking the `gotData` method or your asynchronous data request is still waiting to be returned (and thus undefined).

Comment: When i run `console.log(urls)` in function is working fine. But when i run `console.log(urls)` outside function, Its error as `urls is not defined` I think problem is we cant return urls value to outside function

Comment: @MoomooSoso It will be, `urls` in scoped *only* to that function! `gotData` returns the array so you need to assign that to a variable, see my updated answer.

Comment: when i add `var urls = gotData(/*-- your data -- */);` its show error as `result = data.val() -> Cannot read property 'val' of undefined`

Comment: @MoomooSoso are you passing in the data from Firebase into this function? (you should be!)

Comment: before I add `var urls = gotData(/*-- your data -- */);` it work fine. P.S. I update a whole code.

Comment: urls return value only []. No assign value from gotData(data) T_T